# Convert generic list of double to byte array in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, generics

I am trying to figure this one out. I saw a link on how to convert a list of `int`s to a byte array in C#, but I can't get syntax to work out for me in VB.NET.

Stack Overflow question *[Converting a list of ints to a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097812/converting-a-list-of-ints-to-a-byte-array)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the same function, but pass in a double value rather than an integer value.

```
Dim doubles as New List(Of Double)

doubles.Add(3.14)
doubles.Add(2.614)

Dim bytes() as Byte
bytes = doubles.SelectMany(Function(d) BitConverter.GetBytes(d)).ToArray()
```